# Do ATAs hold Compressed NFTs

Tags: nfts, compression

Are compressed NFTs held by ATAs - looked at DAS and cannot rly figure it out. And if they are, can I find it in Digital Asset Standard Read APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not. Ownership of cNFTs is stored directly in the leaf of the Merkle tree and hashed with the other data.